# Cache mediator support in WSO2 ESB5.0.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

We have mediation applications running on WSO2 ESB4.9.0 and we are planning to migrate onto latest version WSO2 ESB5.0.0.

But in updated version we didn't find cache mediator suppport.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the cache mediator is missing from the UI. As a workaround you can add the cache mediator from the source view. Then it will appear in the UI. Refer the following.

```
<cache scope="per-host"
      collector="false"
      hashGenerator="org.wso2.carbon.mediator.cache.digest.DOMHASHGenerator"
      timeout="20">
      <implementation type="memory" maxSize="100"/>
    </cache>
```

[image]

**Update** : It seems there are some [bug](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/ESBJAVA-4879) fixes for cache mediator as well. The best option will be to build the ESB from source with the latest changes.

Comment: I am getting below exception when I tried to copy the source code of cache mediator.  Even I tried to copy the jars into components/lob folder but no luck                 TID: [-1234] [] [2016-09-26 16:50:11,500] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.config.xml.CacheMediatorFactory} -  Unable to load the hash generator class {org.apache.synapse.config.xml.CacheMediatorFactory}
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.wso2.carbon.mediator.cache.digest.DOMHASHGenerator cannot be found by synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v7

Comment: You can build the whole product not just the cache mediator. Clone product-esb repo and build it from there. https://github.com/wso2/product-esb

Comment: Some confusion here. I've downloaded WSo2 ESB from http://wso2.com/products/enterprise-service-bus/ link, started the server, logged into management console and there  I am trying to create cache mediator in one of the sequence.

Comment: It worked fine for me, it seems DOMHASHGenerator is not there, Can you try building the pack from source?

Comment: Is there any gap in the features/fixes in WSO2 ESB products when you build from source or when you download zip directly

Comment: Yes latest fixes are there when you build it from source.